# smarty assign to javascript external

Tags: javascript, smarty

here in index.tpl

here in javas.js

```
var currentTS = "{literal}{$userid}{/literal}";
alert(currentTS);
```

but there will be alert `{literal}{$userid}{/literal}` not the `$userid`.
any idea?

Comment: also I forgot to mention. you wanna make sure you put the double quotes "" around it only if you want the string value, if it's a integer which from the variable name sounds like a primay unique key you are better off putting no quotes

Answer (score 5):

Smarty only works under php, you can't run it in .js , unless you add .js to php extensions in apache configruations.

On top of that it seems to me that you are trying to access the {$userid} variable from your index.php. That is never gonna happen! unless you include  the file server side like karvonen explained. 
And your `{literal}` tags are unnecessary you start literal when you are gonna use `{` and `}` that are not smarty tags but for javascript, css, etc.. 
and the only time you see them around smarty tags is the other way around as karvonen explained

**here's my suggestion:** in your index.tpl right before including the java.js file do this:

```
<!--index.tpl-->
<script type='text/javascript'>UserID = '{$userid}';</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='pathto/java.js'></script>



/*java.js*/
var currentTS = UserID;
alert(currentTS);
```

Answer (score 2):

Include the javascript file in your index.tpl. If you have it outside your template directory you must use the `file:/...` notation (and use your own path, of cours):

```
<html>
  <head
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  {include file='file:/home/www/mydomain/public_html/js/javas.js'}
  </script>
```

if you have it in your template diretory simply:

```
<html>
  <head
  <script type='text/javascriptä>
  {include file='javas.js'}
  </script>
```

Now Smarty should parse and compile it.

Moreover, it seems to me that you `{literal}{/literal`} are the wrong way around. If you are using curly braces in your js file you should start the js with a {literal} tag and "unliteralize" the smarty variables:

```
{literal}
function test() {
   var name = '{/literal}{$name}{literal}';
   // do something
}
{/literal}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use {literal}
You don't need it here.

{literal} forces to display all { as they are and don't parse smarty code. Therefore {$userid} will be displayed, as it is.

There is no point in displaying it at the place you are.